# How can I use my secondary (nvidia) graphics card

Tags: 16.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

When i run

```
lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'
```

I get

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

and when i try to run something with `optirun` it says me

```
[  115.308714] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[  115.308802] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

How can I set the NVIDIA card as a VGA?

Comment: Did you try `sudo prime-select nvidia`? You also might have to install *nvidia-prime* with `apt-get install nvidia-prime`.

Comment: Ensure that NVIDIA proprietary driver is installed. Ubuntu installed the NVIDIA driver by default while installing (I had opted for third party software installation option during installation). In shell, you can see “nvidia” for the command “lsmod | grep nvidia”

Comment: Have you tried using ARandR?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that more recent NVIDIA hardware/software combinations are unlikely to work well with bumblebee/optirun type solutions. What works reliably for me is:

```
> sudo nvidia-settings
```

And then you select `PRIME Profiles`. Next you toggle `NVIDA (Performance Mode)` to **on**. Finally, you click the `Quit` button and log out of Ubuntu per the pop-up.

[image]

When I log back in, graphics is runs through the GPU rather than the CPU. It is inconvenient sometimes, but usually I want the GPU for a specific workflow.